# I built a jQuery hover effect but it's not working first time (after that it will work well)

Tags: jquery, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="doc_thumb" id="doc_thumb_191"style="";display: inline-table;float: left;"onmouseover="view_file(191);" onmouseout="hide_file(191);"><imgstyle=""src="images">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 function view_file(val) {
    debugger;
    $("#doc_thumb_"+val).hover(

       function() { $("#word_"+val).stop(true, true).show('slide','left',400); },
       function() { $("#word_"+val).stop(true, true).hide('slide','left',400); }

    );
    $("#doc_thumb_"+val).hover(

       function() { $("#pdf_"+val).stop(true, true).show('slide','left',400); },
       function() { $("#pdf_"+val).stop(true, true).hide('slide','left',400); }
    );
}
```

This function is called dynamically and `val` is a dynamic value of my `div` tag.

Comment: please share complete code.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

With following HTML:

```
<div class="doc_thumb" id="doc_thumb_191"style="";display: inline-table;float: left;><imgstyle=""src="images">
    </div>
```

below jQuery code should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div[id^=doc_thumb_").hover(
        function() { 
            //hover in handler
            var currentId = $(this).attr("id");
            var fileNumber = currentId.replace("doc_thumb_","");
            $("#word_"+fileNumber).stop(true, true).show('slide','left',400); 
            $("#pdf_"+fileNumber).stop(true, true).show('slide','left',400);
        },
        function() { 
            //hover out handler
            var currentId = $(this).attr("id");
            var fileNumber = currentId.replace("doc_thumb_","");
            $("#word_"+fileNumber).stop(true, true).hide('slide','left',400); 
            $("#pdf_"+fileNumber).stop(true, true).hide('slide','left',400);
        }
    );

});
```

No need of attaching `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event handler via DOM. Please try.